# Random closed packing of non- overlapping spheres inside a cube using Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, geometry, packing

I am trying to model random closed packing spheres of non-uniform size in a cube using Matlab. There are three constraints in the problem. First, random spheres generated should be bounded within the cube. Second, the spheres should not overlap. Last, the spheres should be closedly packed. I have implemented the first two condition in the code that I have build below. The code is as follows:

```
 function [ c r ] = randomSphere( dims )
 % creating one sphere at random inside [0..dims(1)]x[0..dims(2)]x...
 % In general cube dimension would be 10mm*10mm*10mm
 % radius and center coordinates are sampled from a uniform distribution 
 % over the relevant domain.
 %
 % output: c - center of sphere (vector cx, cy,... )
 %         r - radius of sphere (scalar)
 r = 0.15 + ( 0.55 - 0.15) .* rand(1);% radius varies between 0.15mm - 0.55mm
 c = bsxfun(@times,(dims - 2*r) , rand(1,3)) + r; % to make sure sphere is placed inside the cube

 function not_ovlp = nonOver( centers, rads ) % to make sure spheres do not overlap

 if numel( rads ) == 1
     not_ovlp = true;
     return; % nothing to check for a single or the first sphere
 end

 center_dist = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,centers(1:end-1,:),centers(end,:)).^2,2));
 radsum = rads(end) + rads(1:end-1);
 not_ovlp = all(center_dist >= radsum);

 return;

 function [centers, rads] = sampleSpheres( dims, n ) 
 % main function which is to be called for adding multiple spheres in a cube
 % dims is assumed to be a row vector of size 1-by-ndim
 % For demo take dims = [ 2 2 2 ] and n = 50 

 % preallocate
 ndim = numel(dims);
 centers = zeros( n, ndim );
 rads = zeros( n, 1 );
 ii = 1;
 while ii <= n
      [centers(ii,:), rads(ii) ] = randomSphere( dims );     
      if nonOver( centers(1:ii,:), rads(1:ii) )
           ii = ii + 1; % accept and move on
      end
 end
 disp (centers);
 disp (rads);
```

From this code, am able to get randomly distributed spheres inside a cube but they are not closedly packed. If I increase the number of spheres(n) then it becomes infinite loop and does not generate any answer.

To make it closedly packed my idea is to after generating the first sphere, there should be a constraint in choosing the random center(x, y, z) for the next sphere. It should be close to the position of the first sphere and so on.

Just to give an idea of what am aiming for: [image: This is the sort of closed packing am trying to generate]

Let me know, how can I implement the last constraint.

Comment: have you tried to solve this first for circles in 2D? also this might be helpful for inspiration: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/spherepack.html

Comment: @natan No i haven't tried it for circles in 2D. I think am very close in getting it correct for sphere packing. The good part in my problem is am not interested in generating the highest possible packing efficiency. So not concerned with the packing factor.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your code completely. Are you certain you're not trying to add more spheres than will fit in the cube? With an average radius of `0.35mm` and a cube `2mm x 2mm x 2mm` (is that right?) you should be able to fit barely more than 20 spheres. At the very least you're going to have to implement some sort of backtracking in case you get caught in an unworkable configuration.

Comment: @beaker Yes those are just demo values. You made a good point, am trying to implement some sort of backtracking. Since, it certain that size of the cube and number of spheres should have some relation. Right now, am trying to make sure that spheres take some position that is near to the first sphere and then keep on filling the cube.

Comment: I think you should also use some kind of optimization in your code. For instance, you can use simulate annealing and put the porosity or void space as your objective function. Then, most probably you can minimize the distances/void space.